# How to declare a layout properly so I can use it anywhere in my widget

Tags: qt, layout

This might be a simple question for most of your experts but I've been banging my head on this for the last few hours.

I have this layout which I declare in the header file like this:

```
private:  
    QVBoxLayout *vlayout;
```

I then initialize it in the constructor:

```
QVBoxLayout *vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();  
ui->mainscroll_menu->setWidgetResizable(true);  
ui->mainscroll_menu->widget()->setLayout(vlayout);  

vlayout->setSpacing(1);  
vlayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);  
vlayout->setMargin(0);
```

I then try to use it inside a slot for example:

```
void MainWidget::on_pushButton_clicked()  
{  
    vlayout->addWidget(menuitem);  
}
```

This will compile ok but it will fail during runtime and crash my application. Upon running the debugging, it shows that it crashes when I try to use `vlayout`.

If I initialize the layout inside the slot, it will then work without crashing but that comes with other issues as I have to initialize the layout for each and everytime I want to use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in the constructor:

```
QVBoxLayout *vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
```

This is creating a local variable in the constructor that is shadowing the member variable by the same name. When you try to use the member variable in any other method, you end up using an uninitialized value - hence the crash.

The fix is to simply change the line to:

```
vlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
```

Comment: Thank you!! I feel stupid when the answer is so simple. Kind of shows that I'm not doing a good job at self teaching myself c++. I try to understand the problem on my own before asking any questions but c++ is the most frustrating thing to learn by far. Thank you again, this helped me understand and has solved all sort of weird behaviours in my application.